# Need help using MongoDB with Heroku & Node, Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, express, swig-template

My project goal is to make a checklist-like web app where the user can see what's in the database and also update what's inside it.

Database is simple. Just listing favorite things. Eg {"favorite":"Pie"},{"favorite":"Kitty"}

So far I've figured out how to connect to the database(MongoHQ) and show a single element of data. I've been trying for hours but I'm stumped on:

1. Getting the html file to write whatever data is in the database.
2. Writing the Post form to write to the database.

Please share some insights!

Here's my code.

**.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div>

  <h1>Notepad</h1>
  <p>Favorite things: {{favorite}}</p>
<!--  {% for favorite in doc %}                  <-this doesn't work!
  <p>Favorite things: {{favorite}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
-->  
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**web.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var mongoUri = "mongodb://id:pass@ds------.mongolab.com:-----/heroku_app------";
var cons = require('consolidate');
var app = express(express.logger());

app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('port', process.env.Port || 8080);
app.use(express.bodyParser());

var mydatabase = null;
var myCollection = null;

MongoClient.connect(mongoUri, function(err, db){
    if(!err){
        console.log("We are connected to mongo_lab!");
    }
    mydatabase = db;
    mydatabase.createCollection('test2', function(err, collection){});

    myCollection = mydatabase.collection('favorites');
    //myCollection.insert({'favorite':'Blueberries'}, {w:1}, function(err, result){});
});

var mongoclient_server = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017));

function errorHandler(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.message);
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500);
    res.send("Fix the dam Error!");
}
app.use(errorHandler);

app.get('/notepad', function(req, res, next){
    MongoClient.connect(mongoUri, function(err, db){
        mydatabase.collection("favorites").find().toArray(function(err, doc){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(doc);
            res.render('notepad', doc[0]);
        });
    });
});

var htmlfile = "index.html";
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
var html = fs.readFileSync(htmlfile).toString();
response.send(html);
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
//mongoclient_server.open(function(err, mongoclient_server){   <--if I use this, heroku crashes
//    if(err) throw err;
//    app.listen(port);
//});
```

Comment: Could you post the full structure of the doc? Your logic appears to be aimed at something like this:
`doc = ['favorite1', 'favorite2', ...]`

Comment: I just have a dummy data right now with one key-value pair which is {"favorite":"blueberry"}. I'm trying to make the notepad so that you can add more favorite things to the list. I guess I should be extending the doc to be like {"favorite":["blueberry", "apple", kitten"]}?

Comment: Yes, and then in the template you'll need to reference that array property, like so: `{% for favorite in doc.favorite %}`

Comment: I think the key is in the nunjucks syntax:

`{% for favorite in doc %}` is equivalent to `for (var item in doc) {` in plain javascript. What you want is `{% for favorite in doc.favorite %}` which is `for (var item in doc.favorite) {`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing data from `doc[0]` as locals to your `notepad` view, so basically `notepad` locals will be what is in `doc[0]`.

In your call to `res.render()`, you should specify that your documents reside in the `doc` local, like this:

```
res.render('notepad', {
  doc: doc
});
```

This way your `{% for ... %}` will work.

[Docs for `res.render`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render)